# Programmatically geting teaser of a field other than body

Tags: entities, nodes

I need to get teaser of a custom field. I used the below code that I used for `body`.

```
$fieldContent = field_get_items('node', $nodeObj, 'my_field_name');
$teaser = field_view_value('node', $nodeObj, 'my_field_name', $fieldContent[0],'teaser');
//Below line prints an empty array
print_r($teaser);
$teaser   = drupal_render($teaser);
```

When I try the above code for the field `body` it works. What the code expects from the field to display teaser? How to fix this?

Comment: Is the field hidden in your node type's teaser display settings?

Comment: yes it was. Changing it to 'Default'/'Trimmed' works.. Put your comment as an answer.. it deserves an upvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your node type's display settings for the teaser view mode and verify that the field is not hidden.